# How to use a .pfx certificate in Kubernetes?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I have a .pfx file that a Java container needs to use.

I have created a tls secret using the command

`kubectl create secret tls secret-pfx-key --dry-run=client --cert tls.crt --key tls.key -o yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/tls
metadata:
  name     : secret-pfx-key
  namespace: default
data:
  #cat tls.crt | base64
  tls.crt: base64-gibberish....
  #cat tls.key | base64
  tls.key: base64-gibberish....
```

However, now I cannot understand how to use it. When I add the secret as volume in the pod I can see the two files that are created. But I need the combination of the two in one .pfx file.

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Note: I have read the related stackoverflow questions but could not understand how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

You can [convert](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html) to pfx first, then `kubectl create secret generic mypfx --from-file=pfx-cert=<converted pfx file>`

Mount the secret as a volume in your pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-mypfx
spec:
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
  volumes:
  - name: pfx-volume
    secret:
      secretName: mypfx
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    command: ["ash","-c","cat /path/in/the/container/pfx-cert; sleep 5"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: pfx-volume
      mountPath: /path/in/the/container
```

The above example dump the cert, wait for 5s and exit.